# How to copy some lines from a file and paste to another file in ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I want to copy some lines from a text file and paste it to another file(file a -> file b). I'm using ubuntu.

if file a is like below:

```
&IONS
  upscale           = 100.D0,
/

&CELL
!  cell_dynamics     = 'bfgs'
  press_conv_thr    = 0.01d0
/

ATOMIC_SPECIES
HZ               134.857   hz_s.upf_0.50
Si               28.0855   si_srl_gga.upf
S               32.0650   s_srl_gga.upf

K_POINTS (automatic)
    8    8    8    0    0    0


CELL_PARAMETERS (alat=  1.88972599)
   3.499845546   0.000000000   0.000000000
   0.000000000   3.499845546   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.000000000   7.992795057

ATOMIC_POSITIONS (crystal)
HZ       0.750000000   0.750000000   0.729718998
HZ       0.250000000   0.250000000   0.270281002
Si       0.750000000   0.250000000   0.000000000
Si       0.250000000   0.750000000   0.000000000
S        0.250000000   0.250000000   0.620340894
S        0.750000000   0.750000000   0.379659106
```

I want to extract(copy) the lines from `CELL_PARAMETERS (alat=  1.88972599)` to the last line `S        0.750000000   0.750000000   0.379659106`

and paste it to the last part of 'file b'

How can I do it automatically?(by not using yank and paste)

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
sed -n '/CELL_PARAMETERS/,$p' filea >> fileb
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This small example should solve your problem:

```
$  head a b
==> a <==
abcd
xyz1
foo
1
2
3

==> b <==
####
!!!!

kent$  sed -n '/^foo/,$p' a >> b

kent$  cat b
####
!!!!
foo
1
2
3
```